# Some one bruteforcing my api.php file, How i can hide it but keep use thorut PHP

Tags: .htaccess

My website is www.MultiDown.co.il
And im using api.php (www.multidown.co.il/api.php) to work with some plugins (Jdownloader/Mipony) They connect into my db from api.php.
Some one trying to bruteforce And steal my users passwords, any idea how I can block that and hide it from URL?
look for example:
If you try to get inside: http://multidown.co.il/api.php?user=test&pass=1234567890
You will get error, but if the user/pass will be right, it will show u Verfied.
How i can hide this Without harming the api itself.